# Can i Override the number of instances the tests are running in parallel using NUnit3 Console

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit-console, nunit-3.0

I have a few tests written in c#.net using NUnit3. I have added the number of instances the test cases should run in parallel in assemblyinfo.cs file by [assembly: LevelOfParallelism(4)]. Now every time I run tests, it will run 4 tests in parallel. How can I control this number using console? Can I pass a parameter so that the tests will run only 1 at a time but do not want to change the above value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be possible to override the `LevelOfParallelism` attribute with the `--workers` command line option.

([LevelOfParallelism Docs](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/LevelOfParallelism-Attribute))

([Command line Docs](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line))